# Javascript or jQuery Gridview Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have an **ASP.NET GridView** and multiple **ListBoxes** as Departments, Categories, Faculties etc. ListBoxes and GridView are filled from a database (MSSQL) in codebehind.

I need a **JS** or **jQuery** function that takes selected item's value and filters gridview rows by this value. **For example**, when a department selected from department listbox, it will show only the entries in that department (hide others).

I know, it is not a proper question without sample codes but i really need some hints in this case.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started.

**jQuery**

```
$("#ListBoxID").change(function() {
    $("#" + GridViewID).find('td').not(':contains("' + $(this).val() + '")').parents('tr').hide();
});
```

Not that if your `ListBox.SelectionMode` is set to `Multiple`, `$(this).val()` will contain an array of selected items and you have to handle that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. You could utilize [jQuery Datatables](http://datatables.net/) (which takes your existing `<table>` markup that your gridview generates and powers it up with various useful options). Then you could make use of their API to add in your filtering logic. Here is an example:
   http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html
2. Another option is to code your own jQuery ajax call, that will fire when clicking on a list box item. It would then call a static Web Method (that returns string) in your code behind (and send the selected list box option as a parameter). Your static web method would re-query the database using the parameter value to filter the result. Then you would build a gridview in your code behind, data bind it with the query results, turn the gridview into a html string and return it as a response to your initial jQuery Ajax call. In the `success:` callback of your AJAX call you would grab the response html string and place it into the container html element that holds your Gridview on the page. More about this approach:

   - http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ (explains calling the page method with jQuery)
   - http://encosia.com/boost-aspnet-performance-with-deferred-content-loading/ (slightly different example, it uses ASP.NET AJAX instead of jQuery AJAX to populate html on the page - but pay attention to the static Web Method - it demonstrates how to create a html string.)
3. If this all seems complex, you can use regular postback (not AJAX), by creating a selected index changed event on your listbox, that will re-query the database with the filtered option and rebind the existing gridview.

Hope that this helps

Comment: Hi @samet, did you find any of the answers useful? Did you try any of this - need any help?